# Compiler is refusing to compile correct code in Unity3d C#

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I just added an integer argument to a function definition and added an integer to the only instance where the function is called. an error is generated:

**CustomShaderEditor.cs(44,46): error CS1501: No overload for method `UpdateTexture' takes`0' arguments**

I don't know how to cope with an error of this kind, I would love some advice.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class CustomShader : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public int numTiles = 10;
    public GameObject RenderGameObject;
    public GameObject[] gamObjectClones;    
    public Texture2D ComputeTexture;    
    public ComputeShader ComputeShader; 
    ComputeBuffer wavBuffer ;
    ComputeBuffer computeBuffer ;

    void Start () 
    {
        ResetTexture();
        gamObjectClones = new GameObject[numTiles];
        for (int i=0; i<numTiles; i++)
        {
            gamObjectClones[i] = (GameObject)Instantiate(RenderGameObject, new Vector3(i * 10.0f, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        }

    }

    void Update ()  
    {
        RefreshComputeShaderMaterial();
    }   

    public void RefreshComputeShaderMaterial()
    {       
        for (int i=0; i<numTiles; i++)
        {

            UpdateTexture(  10 );           


            Material m = gamObjectClones[i].GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial;

            if (m.HasProperty("_DataTexture"))
            {
                m.SetTexture("_DataTexture", ComputeTexture);
            }
        }   
    }

    public void ResetTexture()
    {
        int BufferSize = ComputeTexture.width * ComputeTexture.height;
        Color[] ColorBuffer = new Color[BufferSize];
        ComputeTexture.SetPixels(ColorBuffer);
        ComputeTexture.Apply();
    }

    public void SetupTexture()
    {
        int BufferSize = ComputeTexture.width * ComputeTexture.height;
        Color[] ColorBuffer = ComputeTexture.GetPixels();

        for (int i=0; i<BufferSize; i++)
        {
            if ((i&31)==31)
            {
                ColorBuffer[i] = Color.white;
            }
        }

        ComputeTexture.SetPixels(ColorBuffer);
        ComputeTexture.Apply();
    }   

    public void UpdateTexture( int tile )
    {
        int csi;
        csi = ComputeShader.FindKernel("computeGameOfLife");

        if (csi>-1)
        {
            var ran = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1f,100f);

            int BufferSize = ComputeTexture.width * ComputeTexture.height;
            Vector4[] TextureBuffer = new Vector4[BufferSize];
            Color  [] ColorBuffer   = ComputeTexture.GetPixels();

            for (int i=0; i<BufferSize; i++)
            {
                TextureBuffer[i].x = 0;//Mathf.Sin(i/10f);
                TextureBuffer[i].y = 0;
                TextureBuffer[i].z = 0;
                TextureBuffer[i].w = 0;
            }

            computeBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(BufferSize, sizeof(float) * 4);
            computeBuffer.SetData(TextureBuffer);
            ComputeShader.SetBuffer(csi, "DataTexture", computeBuffer);

            //////////////////// patch
            int sBufferSize = 88000 ;
            float[] sTextureBuffer = new float[sBufferSize] ;

            for (int i = 0 ; i < sBufferSize ; i++)
            {
                sTextureBuffer[ i ] = Mathf.Sin( i / ran + 20*Mathf.Sin(i/1000)  ) ;
            }

            ReleaseBuffers();
            print( " sin " + sTextureBuffer[23]);
            wavBuffer = new ComputeBuffer(sBufferSize, sizeof(float)  ) ;
            wavBuffer.SetData(sTextureBuffer);
            ComputeShader.SetBuffer(csi, "re", wavBuffer) ;
             //wavBuffer.Release() ;
            /////////////////////

            ComputeShader.Dispatch(csi, 1, 1, 1);           
            computeBuffer.GetData (TextureBuffer);
            computeBuffer.Release();

            for (int i=0; i<BufferSize; i++)
            {
                ColorBuffer[i].r = TextureBuffer[i].x;
                ColorBuffer[i].g = TextureBuffer[i].y;
                ColorBuffer[i].b = TextureBuffer[i].z;
                ColorBuffer[i].a = TextureBuffer[i].w;
            }

            ComputeTexture.SetPixels(ColorBuffer);
            ComputeTexture.Apply();
        }
    }

    public void ReleaseBuffers() {
        if (wavBuffer != null) wavBuffer.Release();
        wavBuffer = null;
    }   




}
```

Comment: It is very unlikely the line you've marked produces the error you getting. Make sure to read [MCVE] guidance on providing code for such questions. Clean build *may* produce more plausible  error.

Comment: hi i've posted it entirely. the error is written as line 44, I did various scenario checks to confirm that only those two line changes to add a function argument generate the error. when i reloaded unity it said "failed to reload window layout, do you want ot choose defaut/ tall" which is a strange error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UpdateTexture( i ); //'=-='error is for this line

This is not the problem with your code. There is a problem somewhere else. Make sure to save the new code and see whether your old code is still the one being used instead of the new code. Also re-start Unity. If these fails, dump your whole code here for further help because what you have now is NOT the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks good idea. I restarted Unity and am having the same error. it is quoted as line 44 which is the function call. I only change two lines to get the error, adding an integer to the function definition and the function call, and i tried to add a dummy integer addition in the function to use the integer. samer error and the code is responding to changes and saves. I have posted the complete code.

Comment: @comprehensible With your updated complete code, there nothing wrong with your code. This is likely a Unity->Visual studio sync problem. I suggest you Uninstall Visual Studio, Unity. Restart computer then Install Visual Studio, Unity again. This  should solve the problem.

Comment: There was a hidden code called CustomShaderEditor.cs, and not CustomShader.cs ... that i had never seen in the project which also called the function on line 44, and i could only find it if i double clicked on the error message so that it opened the other code, which I hadn't done. it was an obsolete gui layout code that was somewherein the background of the project which i had no idea existed. it's a game of life unity3d compute shader texture update project which i am changing since 1 2 days. thanks. sorry for my absent-mindedness and bad judgement.

Comment: @comprehensible That's fine. I was wondering what happened and why it was deleted. You are welcome.

Comment: @comprehensible CustomShaderEditor sounds a lot like a custom inspector for the CustomShader. Editor gui code looks a lot like the old gui. Its maybe less redundant (though ofc its only editor stuff) than you think? This might also explain why it appeard "hidden" since editor code is seperated from game code (obviously)